# How to display the fetched contacts from android device using phonegap as a checkbox list?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

> I have fetched the contacts from device but they are completely listed out in a single control. I have to list out them in looping structure in checkbox control. Below is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("welcome");
                    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                    options.filter="";
                    options.multiple=true;
                    var fields = ["*"];
                    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);                      
                }
    function onSuccess(contacts) 
    {
        alert('Total Contacts '+contacts.length);
               for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
               {
                   contacts = contacts.sort(compare);                           
                   if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
                    {
                     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "</br>" + contacts[i].displayName;
                     for( var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
                        {
                         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " - " +contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
                     // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " - " +contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type;
                        }  
                      }
               }
     }
    function compare(a,b) {  
         if (a.displayName > b.displayName)
            return 1;
          if (a.displayName < b.displayName)
             return -1;    
         // return 0;
        }
    function onError()
    {
    alert("Some Error Occured");
    }
</script>
```

> And below is the html body structure

```
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p >Create Contact</p>
<p id="demo"> </p><p id="demo_no">no.</p></body>
```

> Please help me out for this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want the final list to look like?

Comment: I want to display every record on a new checkbox. so that i can select multiple and create groups. as well i need to send this data from index.js to new created page that is contact.html. Now did you get what i want.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your demo element to a **[jQM controlgroup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/controlgroup-dynamic/)**:

```
<h1>Example</h1>
<p >Create Contact</p>         
<div id="demo" data-role="controlgroup"></div>
```

Then in your script,

you only need to sort contacts once, so move the sort call outside the for loop.

for each contact with phone numbers, create a checkbox input and a label.

finally add all the checkboxes and labels to the controlgroup's **[container](http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/#method-container)** element, tell jQM to **[enhance](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)** the checkboxes, and refresh the controlgroup:

```
var html = '';
contacts = contacts.sort(compare); 
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
{
    if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
    {
        html += '<input type="checkbox" name="chk' + i + '" id="chk' + i + '">';
        html += '<label for="chk' + i + '">' + contacts[i].displayName;
        for( var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
        {
            html += " / " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
        }
        html += "</label>";
    }
}
$("#demo").controlgroup("container").empty().append(html);    
$("#demo").enhanceWithin().controlgroup( "refresh" );
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3tLL0jeL/)**